# EF Code First: Model Configuration

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework-4.1, ef-code-first

I'll try to be as clear as possible:

My goal: to read the model configuration I declared in my overridden `OnModelCreating` inside my Entity class derived from `DbContext`.

Reason: To build a generic `void Update<T>(T toUpdate)` method on my data layer, where I get which fields are the primary key for T, retrieve them on the passed `toUpdate` object and use them in the `Set<T>().Find` method.

This would allow me to not hard-code Find logic for every type of entity I handle.

I need to retrieve the stored entity to apply updates, like this:

```
var retrievedItem = _entities.Set<T>().Find(myRetrievedKeyValues);
_entities.Entry(retrievedItem).CurrentValues.SetValues(toUpdate);
```

I'm stuck at the point that in my `_entities` instance (which is my entities class derived from `DbContext` of course) I can't seem to find where the model configuration is stored.

Anyone can point me in the right direction?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can find the code how to retrieve the key property names of an entity type `YourEntity` here:

[Entity Framework code first. Find primary key](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7253943/entity-framework-code-first-find-primary-key/7253992#7253992)

And then retrieve the values:

```
public Update<T>(T toUpdate)
{
    // Code from link above with YourEntity = T

    List<object> myRetrievedKeyValues = new List<object>();
    foreach (var keyName in keyNames)
        myRetrievedKeyValues.Add(toUpdate.GetType().GetProperty(keyName)
            .GetValue(toUpdate, null));

    var retrievedItem = _entities.Set<T>().Find(myRetrievedKeyValues.ToArray());
    _entities.Entry(retrievedItem).CurrentValues.SetValues(toUpdate);
}
```

Expect that you'll have a quite slow `Update` method because you must use reflection for this generic approach.

Also don't forget that `CurrentValues.SetValues` will only update scalar and complex properties. It does not help you to update navigation properties. You will have to use non-generic code to update the relationships which are specific to each entity type.

Comment: That was perfect, and I already wrote the rest of the code exactly as you posted it. Works like a charm.