# Dynamically attach entry to context

Tags: asp.net, entity-framework-6, dbcontext

I am using .Net 4.5 and Entity Framework 6 to create a REST Web API. 
In my Update methods I need to attach the object recieved in the web api, back to the dbcontext. I have achieved this using the code below. What I want to do now, is to make this code reusable so that I can call AttachToContext for any object in the model.

I understand that I have to use generic type T and TEntity, but I cannot find any suitable examples.

```
//Repository.cs
public void UpdateOrderItem(OrderItem orderItem)
            {
                try
                {
                    AttachToContext(orderItem);
                    _context.SaveChanges();
                }
                catch (Exception e)
                {
                }
            }

            private void AttachToContext(OrderItem orderItem)
            {
                var entry = _context.Entry<OrderItem>(orderItem);
                if (entry.State == EntityState.Detached)
                {
                    var attachedEntity = FindExistingEntity(orderItem.Id);
                    if (EntityExists(attachedEntity))
                    {
                        UpdateEntityValues(attachedEntity, orderItem);
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        entry.State = EntityState.Modified;
                    }
                }

            }

            private OrderItem FindExistingEntity(int id)
            {
                var set = _context.Set<OrderItem>();
                return set.Find(id);
            }

            private void UpdateEntityValues(OrderItem existing, OrderItem updated)
            {
                var attachedEntry = _context.Entry(existing);
                attachedEntry.CurrentValues.SetValues(updated);
            }

            private bool EntityExists(object entity)
            {
                return entity != null;
            }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `AttachToContext` has dependency to primary key property, `orderItem.Id`, to change it into dynamic, you can introduce an interface and implement to all entities you have or just passing the id as parameters.

**Interface**

```
public interface IEntity
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
}
public class OrderItem : IEntity
{
    // body
}
```

Then modify the `AttachToContext` as follow.

```
private void AttachToContext<T>(T entity) where T : class, IEntity
{
    var entry = _context.Entry(entity);
    if (entry.State == EntityState.Detached)
    {
        var attachedEntity = FindExistingEntity<T>(entity.Id);
        if (EntityExists(attachedEntity))
        {
            UpdateEntityValues(attachedEntity, entity);
        }
        else
        {
            entry.State = EntityState.Modified;
        }
    }
}
private T FindExistingEntity<T>(int id) where T : class
{
    var set = _context.Set<T>();
    return set.Find(id);
}
private void UpdateEntityValues<T>(T existing, T updated) where T : class
{
    var attachedEntry = _context.Entry(existing);
    attachedEntry.CurrentValues.SetValues(updated);
}
```

The usage would be `AttachToContext(orderItem);`.

**Passing The Keys**

```
private void AttachToContext<T>(T entity, params object[] id) where T : class
{
    var entry = _context.Entry(entity);
    if (entry.State == EntityState.Detached)
    {
        var attachedEntity = FindExistingEntity<T>(id);
        if (EntityExists(attachedEntity))
        {
            UpdateEntityValues(attachedEntity, entity);
        }
        else
        {
            entry.State = EntityState.Modified;
        }
    }
}
private T FindExistingEntity<T>(object[] id) where T : class
{
    var set = _context.Set<T>();
    return set.Find(id);
}
private void UpdateEntityValues<T>(T existing, T updated) where T : class
{
    var attachedEntry = _context.Entry(existing);
    attachedEntry.CurrentValues.SetValues(updated);
}
```

The usage would be `AttachToContext(orderItem, orderItem.Id);`.

Another alternative would be using object set to get the primary key properties, then using reflection to get the value. To get the primary key properties has been explained in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7253943/968303).