# Linq/Dynamic Linq orderby first column (or primary key)

Tags: c#, linq, pagination, dynamic-linq

I've written a grid component and I've decided to make having no sortable columns (on the grid) an option.

Serverside, my query does pagination using `.Skip` and looks similar to this

```
public object PaginateQueryAsJson<TQuery>(TQuery query)
        where TQuery : IQueryable<object>, IEnumerable<object>
    {
      if (page < 1)
        page = 1;
      if (pageSize < 1)
        pageSize = 1;

      int recordCount = needsCount ? query.Count() : -1;

      if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(sortColumnName))
        query = (TQuery)query.OrderBy(sortColumnName + " " + (isAscending ? "ASC" : "DESC"));

      return new
      {
        results = query.Skip((page - 1) * pageSize)
                       .Take(pageSize).ToList(),
        recordCount = recordCount
      };
    }
```

My issue is that when `sortColumnName` is null or empty, `.Skip` complains with `The method 'Skip' is only supported for sorted input in LINQ to Entities. The method 'OrderBy' must be called before the method 'Skip'`.

I'd like to have my helper function automatically apply a default orderby either via the first column in the table or (ideally) the primary key. I realize a solution is to explicitly specify a fallback column as an argument, but I'd like to avoid that if possible.

Comment: If it's LINQ to Entities, are you using EntityFramework? What version?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7253943/entity-framework-code-first-find-primary-key

Comment: as a hack you can just `OrderBy(x => true)`